# Number of solution of $|x|^2-5|x|+6=0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, modular-arithmetic

**Problem:** What will be the number of distinct real solution of $|x|^2-5|x|+6=0$ ?

**Solution:**

> Case1: When $x<0$, then $x=-2,-3$
>
> Case2: When $x>0$, then $x=2,3$

So number of solution is 4, am I right or making some mistake? As this a quadratic equation and the number of solutions must be equal to 2.

Comment: Your answer is correct. You get $|x|=2$ or  $|x|=3$. The equation is not strictly a quadratic equation, but it is quadratic in form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|x|^2-5|x|+6=0 $ is aquadratic equation for $|x|$ ! (and not for $x$). We have

$|x|^2-5|x|+6=(|x|-3)(|x|-2) $, hence

$|x|^2-5|x|+6=0 $  $\iff $ $|x|=3$ or $|x|=2$ $\iff x \in \{-2,2,-3,3\}$

Answer (score 3):

This is a quadratic equation with absolute values..

You can factor this like this
$$(|x|-3)(|x|-2)=0$$
So..either
$$|x|=3 \Leftrightarrow x=\pm3$$
or$$|x|=2\Leftrightarrow x=\pm2$$
So your solutions are correct..

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.

It is a quadratic equation in $|x|$. Or you could set $y=|x|$, then:
$$y^2-5y+6=0 \iff y=2 \vee y = 3$$
So with $y=|x|$, you get:
$$|x|=2 \implies x = \pm 2 \quad\mbox{and}\quad |x|=3 \implies x = \pm 3$$

Comment: You meant to write $y^2 - 5\color{red}{y} + 6 = 0 \iff y = 2 \vee y = 3$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Of course, well spotted and thanks.